# Custom View Not Showing When Dynamically Added

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, view

At a loss here. Searched far and wide and can't find an answer to this question...

I have an XML layout where I have a relative layout that I am using as a place holder for different views.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relVariableLayoutPlaceHolder"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"

    android:background="@color/white"
    >

</RelativeLayout>
```

In my activity, I have a button for the user to press and when they press it, I want the custom `ClockView` to be created and dynamically added. Note that the `_variableLayout` is setting perfectly in the `onCreate` method:

```
public void onStartTimeClick(View view)
{
    //Clean up any left over views
    _variableLayout.removeAllViews();

    //Add clock view
    ClockView clockView = new ClockView(_context);
    _variableLayout.addView(clockView);
}
```

Problem is that when the button is pressed, nothing happens on the screen. I can, however see it when I tap a `TextView` that is also on the screen.

I uploaded some images here of the before and after clicking the `TextView`:
http://imgur.com/a/9lebv

I would imagine this has something to do with the screen not being refreshed after the clock view is drawn but I have tried every combination of `invalidate()` and `requestLayout()` I can think of. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For historical purposes, I felt that I should mention that after a lot of debugging I figured out that my problem was in the `onMeasure` and `onLayout` functions of the `ClockView`. Basically they were poorly formed and not measuing the subviews properly for the `onLayout` function to handle properly.

Once I got those ironed out, everything was working as expected.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try setting the LayoutParams?

```
public void onStartTimeClick(View view)
{
    //Clean up any left over views
    _variableLayout.removeAllViews();

    //Add clock view
    ClockView clockView = new ClockView(_context);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layout_params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    clockView.setLayoutParams(layout_params);
    _variableLayout.addView(clockView);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I am actually declaring the layout params in the ClockView object, but I removed that and tried it your way just to be sure. Same result.

Comment: You could enable some debug options on the Android device to see what is being rendered. And there is also the Hierarchy Viewer from the Android tools to inspect it: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/hierarchy-viewer.html

Comment: Interesting... When I click the Dump Hierarchy Button from the Android tools window, the ClockView appears on my device. So, the view is obviously there, it just isn't showing on the device initially. Still at a loss but at least this proves I am not crazy.

Comment: Is the visibility in your xml set to hidden? And is the view layout actually loaded?

Comment: I wasn't specifying anything for `visibility`, but tried setting to `visible` anyway. Same result. 

I can see that the view is actually loaded in the Device Monitor under the allocation tracker tab and it is on Thread 1 (UI Thread). So it is loading, it is just not showing until some other action is taken (i.e. tapping a textview on the screen or dumping the view hierarchy from the Device Monitor like you suggested).